# Google compute commited use/resevation doesnt use my existing instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-compute-api

I have created instance with same configuration as mentioned in the Commmited use discount/reservation seciton, yet when i goto Reservations, it shows it is currently using none.

reservationslist

[image]

reservation configuration

[image]

instance configuration

[image]

The reservation type in instance is set as "Automatic", but it doesnt automatically detect and match, they both are in same regions and zones. Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the post Hemanth, everything in my instance was matching but still its not attached to the reservation.

I resolved the issue by creating another instance, and this time while creating the instance, I expanded the "Advnaced Options" in the create instance page, and manually choose the Reservation i wanted it to consume. And it worked!

Answer (score 2):

- As per official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources#consuming_reserved_instances), VM can only consume a reservation if the
  properties for both the VM and reservation are matching .
- In this consumption model, existing and new instances automatically
  count against the reservation if those instances' properties match
  the reserved instance's properties
- A VM instance can consume a reservation only if all of the following
  properties for both the VM and

  > the reservation match exactly:
  >
  > ```
  >     Project
  >     Zone
  >     Machine type
  >     Minimum CPU platform
  >     GPU type and count
  >     Local SSD type and count
  > ```
- Refer to this  [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview#requirements) explaining to you the requirements and
  restrictions for compute engine Vm creations
- Follow this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources#consuming_instances_from_any_matching_reservation) for the step by step process of how  to Consume instances from any matching reservation.